# Changing words in list to lower case

Tags: java, string, list, linked-list

```
/** Read the sequence of words on INPUT, and return as a List.  If LINKED,
 *  use a linked representation.  Otherwise, use an array representation.
 */
static List<String> readList(Scanner input, boolean linked) {
    List<String> L;
    if (linked) {
        L = new LinkedList<String>();
    } else {
        L = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        L.add(input.next());
    }
    for (String word : L) {
        word = word.toLowerCase();
    }
    return L;
}
```

This is the code I have for reading words from a text file and returning it as a list. However, I want to make all the words in the file lower case but the toLowerCase method does not work. Any advice on how to make them all lower case?

Comment: You forgot to add word string to list

Comment: I'm afraid markdown doesn't work inside code blocks, so using ** for emphasis won't work

Comment: Yea, I realized after I put in the ** that markdown doesn't work inside code blocks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reassigning `word` will have no effect on what's contained in the list. Why not just call `toLowerCase()` as you're adding to the list?

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    L.add(input.next().toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: Ah, this answer is perfect! Did not know you could use two methods at the same time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. You need to replace them inside your list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < L.length(); ++i) {
    L.set(i, L.get(i).toLowerCase();
}
```

Or, you can just do the `toLowerCase()` on adding to the list.

```
while (input.hasNext()) {
    L.add(input.next().toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: This will perform poorly for linked lists.

Comment: @arshajii Unless someone is typing in War and Peace into the scanner, this will not matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
L.add(input.next().toLowerCase());
```